# Horizontal Scrolling to section - but not through whole page

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have got a horizontal scrolling website from 
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/06/02/smooth-vertical-or-horizontal-page-scrolling-with-jquery/

with the code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>      
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('ul.nav a').bind('click',function(event){
                var $anchor = $(this);
                $('html, body').stop().animate({
                    scrollLeft: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().left
                }, 2500,'easeInOutExpo');
             });
        });
    </script>
```

which makes the page scrolling to the sections when clicking on a link.

The problem is I have many sections now (20) and I don't want the page scroll through all sections, when clicking on a link, the effect should only slide left one (!) page further.

Is this possible?

Comment: Sorry, but is there no solution for that? Really looking out and ask several friends...